# Opened up a .iqy file yesterday in Excel, now every time I try to open a new workbook, Excel tries to open up this file

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I downloaded a sharepoint list as an .iqy file and used it in a Excel workbook. But, now when ever I open any Excel workbook it tries to open that file. To try and fix the issues I've:

-Deleted the .iqy file, now Excel just gives me the prompt it can't find the file.

-Removed the connection from the original workbook, but every new workbook still gives me an error looking for it.

-In the Trust Center, set Excel to not open untrusted .iqy files, still not working.

The connection to the iqy file does not appear in any new or old workbooks, and isn't in my recent connections. Also weirdly, it's trying three times to open the file (I have to click "OK" on three separate dialog boxes about the file missing).

Any ideas how to stop excel from trying to open this file every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it after stumbling through all the option in Excel.  It had nothing to do with the connection. Somehow, the file was added to the "Add-In" list, so I had to remove it as an Add-In. I'll leave this question up for posterity.